# Convert DateTime object of java to string in js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, datetime, restangular

I m developing a java application. In this I am using Restangular service , angular js and spring frame work. 
I am passing DateTime Object from restangular call to js. My restangular code is -

```
@GET
@Path("/try")
@Timed
public DateTime create() {
    return new DateTime("2016-05-30T12:10:30.407+05:30");
}
```

And in js I want this object as string. My js code is -

```
$scope.try = function () {
    console.log("Hi")
    Restangular.one('tasks/try').get().then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
};
```

In this code the returned restangular object is in form `2016-05-30T12:10:30.407+05:30` but in JS I recieve it as `[2016, 6, 2, 16, 55, 52, 931]`
What can I do so that in JS I get this datetime object as `2016-05-30T12:10:30.407+05:30`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you use spring mvc or jersy?

Comment: I used angular js v1.3.16, jersey client v2.22.2 and spring.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
data = [2016, 6, 2, 16, 55, 52, 931];

var thisDate = new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(Date, [null].concat(data)));
```

Here we are basically passing `Date` function with all the elements in your data array programmatically.

**ALTER**

this method will be a bit long but will give you a timestamp by which you can convert to any formate

```
function convertToTimeStamp (array) {
    var str = array[0] + "," + array[1] + "," + array[2];
    _ts = new Date(str).getTime()
    timeStamp = _ts + (array[3]*3600 + array[4]*60 + array[5])*1000 + array[6];
    return timeStamp;
}
```

now you can call `convertToTimeStamp(array)` to get a timeStamp value

you can convert the timeStamp to any format by converting it to a date Object
`new Date(timeStamp)`

Comment: It gives invalid Date

Comment: are you sure you are passing the data properly because it is working for me perfectly.

Comment: Yes I am sure. Because previously I am working with dropwizard frame work and it work perfectly and now I am switch to spring then it is not working

Comment: the timestamp which this function is return is wrong

Comment: For the above function to work properly you will have to make sure that `array[1]` is month and `array[2]` is the date.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114103/discussion-between-parita-porwal-and-megamind).